# How to fix "Potential unnecessary eager load detected on `LogEntry.user`"

Tags: python, django, optimization, query-optimization, select-n-plus-1

I'm creating a new Django 2.2 project with plugin `nplusone`(https://github.com/jmcarp/nplusone). When I try to go on /admin URL I get a next error “Potential unnecessary eager load detected on `LogEntry.user`”
This problem appears when I have at least 1 record in DB.

models.py

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    preview_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Post'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Posts'
        ordering = ['-id']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post', args=(self.slug,))
```

admin.py

```py
admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

DEBUG SQLs

```sql
SELECT "django_session"."session_key", "django_session"."session_data", "django_session"."expire_date" FROM "django_session" WHERE ("django_session"."expire_date" > '2019-04-30 06:11:28.376554' AND "django_session"."session_key" = 'hbwpegj1vpvkv5wdkbqr38ty55s3cm38'); args=('2019-04-30 06:11:28.376554', 'hbwpegj1vpvkv5wdkbqr38ty55s3cm38')
```

```sql
SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."id" = 1; args=(1,)
```

```sql
SELECT "django_admin_log"."id", "django_admin_log"."action_time", "django_admin_log"."user_id", "django_admin_log"."content_type_id", "django_admin_log"."object_id", "django_admin_log"."object_repr", "django_admin_log"."action_flag", "django_admin_log"."change_message", "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined", "django_content_type"."id", "django_content_type"."app_label", "django_content_type"."model" FROM "django_admin_log" INNER JOIN "auth_user" ON ("django_admin_log"."user_id" = "auth_user"."id") LEFT OUTER JOIN "django_content_type" ON ("django_admin_log"."content_type_id" = "django_content_type"."id") WHERE "django_admin_log"."user_id" = 1 ORDER BY "django_admin_log"."action_time" DESC  LIMIT 10; args=(1,)
```

Answer (score 3):

I found N+1 to rarely be happy with Django admin - either related entries (like user groups) are loaded lazily and it makes a N+1 problem in big listings, or they are prefetched() and then it's on single-user pages that an "unnecessary eager load" is detected.

The problem is that the same base ModelAdmin querysets are used for listing pages and for single-object pages, so avoiding both problems is not easy.

Until someone comes with an easy solution to create different "prefetch" querysets for different admin pages, I've whitelisted these models like so. Just check with the django debug toolbar that no N+1 requests happen on these admin pages.

```
NPLUSONE_WHITELIST = [
    {"model": "admin.LogEntry", "field": "user"},
    {"model": "accounts.User", "field": "groups"},
]
```